# Traverse REST Api URL using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest

Using PowerShell I am trying to invoke a webrequest that reads the entrypoint of the first request `$defUrl` and then the subsequent endpoint inside each URL.

[image]

The above returns after `$UrlParsed`:

[image]

I then add this to the first image in order to transverse the subsequent endpoints.

```
foreach ($Url in $UrlsParsed) {
  Invoke-WebRequest -uri $UrlsParsed -Credential $cred
}
```

After the `foreach` loop has been added I get the following error.

[image]

The information I would like to get, are at different depths within that URL.

Need some insight on what I may be doing wrong and suggestions on how I could fix this.

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code or errors. Include the information in textform whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
foreach ($Url in $UrlsParsed) {
  Invoke-WebRequest -uri $UrlsParsed -Credential $cred
}
```

into this:

```
foreach ($Url in $UrlsParsed) {
  Invoke-WebRequest -uri $Url -Credential $cred
}
```

Comment: tried that previously to no success. To my understanding, each individual request should the be passed.
Thinking I might need to create a new object and then use that to invoke a new request via the loop.

Comment: Yes I ought to be clearer.
The same exception is thrown.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code and error message(s).

Comment: Our application exposes a list of application statuses via a json api (webpage). 
When i read that via a posh rest request method. It first shows a list of all the endpoints like this

[
{
"serviceUrl": "http://demo.galacticempire.co.uk/tie-fighter/api/v2/services/d3ebf2ac-eec0-401a-872b-bde516b5d3bf",
"level": "ERROR"
}} .....

Comment: Show, don't tell. Update your question.

Comment: Added new info to question above.

Answer (score 0):

After some help and much trial and error, got the results I wanted. Commented code as appropriate.

```
$user = "darthmaul"
$pwd = "#deathStarOrder66" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

#This Url exposes all the service endpoint from a top level.
$defUrl = "https://weaponsTest1.galacticempire.co.uk/star-destroyer/api/v2/service_states?limit=1000"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user,$pwd)
#connect to the first page that exposes all the URL
$stackStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defUrl -Credential $cred

#appends only the service url for an individual service
$parsedUrls = $stackStatus.serviceUrl
#secure requests required else the call fails
$UrlsParsed = $parsedUrls.Replace("http","https")

#for each service found perform an addition call to determine the status of the service via a foreach loop 
foreach ($Url in $UrlsParsed)
{
    #use the individual url
    $sep = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Credential $cred
    #select specific table you want to display and rename as you see fit.
    $svcStatus = $sep | select @{name="Response";Expression ={$_.statuscode}}, @{name="Status";Expression ={$_.statusdescription}} 
    #convert from json so you can select the field you want more easily.
    $svcCall = $sep | ConvertFrom-Json | select displayname, serviceTypeUrl, port, serviceport

    #in order to join those 2 variables together ($svcStatus & $svcCall)
    # add new members to the x.status object by appending svcCall.X to make it look like they are part of the object svcStatus.
    #
    $svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name displayname -Value $svcCall.displayname
    $svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name serviceTypeUrl -Value $svcCall.serviceTypeUrl
    $svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name port -Value $svcCall.port
    $svcStatus | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name servicePort -Value $svcCall.servicePort

    #print out to view.
    $svcStatus | fl
}
```